# Image Loading loads only last image

Tags: javascript

```
//javascript
var img_prev=document.querySelectorAll('.img_prev_save');
img_previewer(img_prev);

function img_previewer(elem){
    if(!document.querySelector('.img_preview'))
    {
        var new_div=document.createElement('DIV');
        new_div.setAttribute('class','img_preview');
        var new_img=document.createElement('IMG');

        console.log(elem);
        for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
            var select=elem[i];

            if(select.value!=null ||select.value!='')
            {
                var img_link=select.value;
                var img_arr=img_link.split(',');
                //console.log(img_arr);
                for(var j=0;j<img_arr.length;j++){
                    new_img.src='filemanager/'+img_arr[j];
                    new_div.appendChild(new_img);

                    elem[i].parentNode.insertBefore(new_div,elem[i]);  
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //elements with .img_prev_save
    <input type="hidden" class="img_prev_save" id="feat_img" name="feat_img" value="uploads/1436093205.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" class="img_prev_save" id="gall_imgs" name="gall_imgs" value="uploads/fireworks.png,uploads/1435455457.jpg">
```

The script loop shows every value being processed. But the actual output is only the last image 'uploads/1435455457.jpg'. I can't seem to find what i am doing wrong. Help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code. You are rewriting your `new_img.src`. Thats because `createElement('IMG')` creates an img **object** :

> **Create an Image Object**:
>   You can create an  element by using the document.createElement()
>   method [1]

```
    for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
        var select=elem[i];
        var img_link=select.value;
        var img_arr=img_link.split(',');

        for(var j=0;j<img_arr.length;j++){
          var new_img=document.createElement('IMG');
          new_img.src=img_arr[j];
          new_img.width = 100;
          new_div.appendChild(new_img);
          elem[i].parentNode.insertBefore(new_div,elem[i]);
        }
    }
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2B0V2z1q58MnlGgvRSZd

```js
//javascript
var img_prev=document.querySelectorAll('.img_prev_save');
img_previewer(img_prev);

function img_previewer(elem){
    if(!document.querySelector('.img_preview'))
    {
        var new_div=document.createElement('DIV');
        new_div.setAttribute('class','img_preview');

        for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
            var select=elem[i];
            var img_link=select.value;
            var img_arr=img_link.split(',');
            
            for(var j=0;j<img_arr.length;j++){
              var new_img=document.createElement('IMG');
              new_img.src=img_arr[j];
              new_img.width = 100;
              new_div.appendChild(new_img);
              elem[i].parentNode.insertBefore(new_div,elem[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2B0V2z1q58MnlGgvRSZd
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" class="img_prev_save" id="feat_img" name="feat_img" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Tetris_Z.svg/500px-Tetris_Z.svg.png" />
<input type="hidden" class="img_prev_save" id="gall_imgs" name="gall_imgs" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7b/Tetris_S.svg/1280px-Tetris_S.svg.png,https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Tetris_T.svg" />
</body></html>
```

<kbd>[1] http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are simply trying to append three images to your div, the problem is that you are only creating one new image as opposed to creating images for each each value from your inputs.  Just move the line `var new_img=document.createElement('IMG');` to the top of the second nested for loop.

Here's a fiddle for example. https://jsfiddle.net/7xxo0u6f/

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the same image with different sources. Better create 3 different images and append in the div. Just like how @rgbchris suggested.